Counting $10$ length paths in a $2 \times 4$ rectangle with distance $6$ units from start to end meaning negative moves allowed?
How many different routes of length 10 units (each side is 1 unit) are there to traverse from lower left corner (point A) to top right corner (point B) in a rectangle with 2 rows and 4 column cells each without moving on the sides repeatedly?
You can use any knowledge to answer this (I have some Math Olympiad background). Total length from A to B is 6 units (2U's [Ups] and 4R's [Rights]). So for the additional 10 - 6 = 4 units of lengths we need them in pairs (since they need to cancel out). How to count further? Any help is appreciated. Thank you
Image added


By the "sides" you mean the periphery of the grid ?

Oh I added the picture for ease

No edge can be traversed twice, correct?

Is the interpretation that you can't retrace your path on any segment on the boundary segments, whereas you can do so freely on all other segments correct ? If so, confirm, else tell what exactly  "without moving on the sides repeatedly" means.

Oh I think we cannot retrace any line segment (on the boundary or otherwise). We can retrace a point only. In other words no edge can be traversed twice, that's right.

This question is a classic example of the fact that

Sometimes, even the smartest way of counting may also not be smart enough

I've solved it with brute force




(PS: I'm not sure if I've committed any error; feel free to point out if you find any. Also, if anybody knows a better way to calculate, do let me know. I'll be grateful.)

This was one hell of a question

verified your answer with a python script. 66 is correct. i also shared the pyhon script in a answer so others can build on it.

The answer 66 seems correct. A brute force python search also resulted in 66
import itertools as it
import numpy as np
H=4
V=2
detours=["LLRR", "LDRU", "DDUU"]
combi=[list("RRRRUU")+list(detour) for detour in detours]

# so we create all permuations of the 3 combinations of normal moves and de-tours
# this would create many duplicates but since we use set comprehension
# each possible move will be there only once.
# certainly not the most efficient way but 
# only takes fractions of a seconds anyways

moves={move for move in it.chain(*[it.permutations(p) for p in combi])}
print("total number of moves to consider",len(moves))


def pos(pin,move):
  """
    pin position in (x,y) pair
    move a letter indicating the move direction
    returns a tuple of (x,y,hidx,vidx,mv)
    where x y is the position after move
    hidx and vidx is the index of the horizontal and
    vertical nodes that is touched and
    mv is either 'H' or 'V'
  """
  x,y=pin
  hindex,vindex=x,y
  mv='H'
  match move:
    case 'R':
        hindex=x
        x+=1
    case 'L':
        x-=1
        hindex=x
    case 'U':
        vindex=y
        y+=1
        mv='V'
    case 'D':
        y-=1
        vindex=y
        mv='V'
    case _: assert False,"illegal direction"
  pout=(x,y,hindex,vindex,mv)
  return pout

def domoves(m):
    """
      do the moves in list m
      returns a tuple (xmax,xmin,ymax,ymin,edgemax,m)
      with the minimum and maximum x and y positions to see if
      we left the field
      and the maximum number edges we traversed
      so should be 1 in order not to move twice on an edge
    """
    hedge=np.zeros((H,V+1))
    vedge=np.zeros((H+1,V))
    x,y,hidx,vidx=0,0,0,0
    xmax=0
    xmin=0
    ymax=0
    ymin=0
    for move in m:
        x,y,hidx,vidx,mv=pos((x,y),move)
        xmax=max(x,xmax)
        xmin=min(x,xmin)
        ymax=max(y,ymax)
        ymin=min(y,ymin)
        if xmax <= H and xmin >= 0 and ymax <= V and ymin >=0:
            if mv=='H':
                hedge[hidx,vidx] += 1
            else:
                vedge[hidx,vidx] += 1
    hmax=np.max(hedge)
    vmax=np.max(vedge)
    edgemax=max(hmax,vmax)
    assert x==H and y==V
    return (xmax,xmin,ymax,ymin,edgemax,m)

mres=[domoves(mv) for mv in moves]
mvalid=[m for xmax,xmin,ymax,ymin,emax,m in mres if xmax <= H and xmin >= 0 and ymax <= V and ymin >= 0 and emax == 1]
print(len(mvalid))


